# Reactivate Push & Pull buttons in RStudio

Tags: r, git, github, ssh, rstudio

For the past three weeks I've been working on my personal iMac, developing a graphical analysis. It was already linked to a GitHub repository, but I kept working locally until I had something substantial to push up to GitHub. Today I tried to push the changes to GitHub and got the message that GitHub no longer supports https: with password authentication.

No problem, I thought. I already had ssh setup and was using it for non-R projects. So, snooping around the Internet, I came across instructions such as [these](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories#adding-a-remote-repository) and changed the urls from https to ssh.

But somewhere along the way, RStudio decided to gray out the buttons for Pull & Push under the Git tab.

How does one reactivate the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure first your SSH URL works from command line:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote -v             # do you see an SSH URL git@github.com:<me>/<myrepo>?
git ls-remote             # do you see remote branches SHA1?
```

Then, you would need to reference your private key in your RStudio settings

[image: https://community.rstudio.com/uploads/default/optimized/3X/b/b/bbbaa4fad4b1d5dd54ea75e98f8d55364a032623_2_513x499.png]